# pass the sum of checked checkboxes to html text input

Tags: html, ajax

hi every body im new in coding ,here im trying to evaluate the sum of of values of checked checkboxes and pass the sum to html text input i dont no how  i appreciate
help , this is my code:

```html
 Aroma Massage:<input type="checkbox" name="Aroma massage" id="check1" value="55">
        Swedish Massage:<input type="checkbox" name="Swedish massage" id="check2" value="50">
        Hot Stone Massage:<input type="checkbox" name="Hot Stone massage" id="check3" value="70">
        Stress Recovery Massage:<input type="checkbox" name="Stress recovery massage" id="check4" value="25">
        Thai Massage:<input type="checkbox" name="Thai massage" id="check5" value="60">
        
        <div id="tot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // cache the inputs and bind the events
    var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
    $inputs.on('change', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $inputs.each(function() {
        // iterate and add it to sum only if checked
           if(this.checked)
               sum += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#price").val(sum);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check if what you want is similar to this?? let me know

```js
var sum=0;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
 if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
  sum += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
}else{
  sum -= parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
}

  $('.sum').val(sum);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="60">
<input type="checkbox" value="20">
<input type="checkbox" value="30">
<input type="checkbox" value="50">

<input type="text" class="sum">
```

Comment: @Abdallah Abu Hazeem please check if this is something that you want.

Answer (score 0):

just use this https://jsfiddle.net/82atpthr/

add this javascript

just use this https://jsfiddle.net/82atpthr/

add this javascript

```
var total = 0; 

function gettotal(item) {
    if(item.checked){
        total+= parseInt(item.value);
    } else {
        total-= parseInt(item.value);
    }
    //alert(total);
    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = total + " /-";
}
```

and add this to the checkboxes `onclick="gettotal(this);"`

Answer (score 0):

I made a vanilla JS solution for the recursion method (used in Purushothaman’s post). If you have a very great number of inputs you have to use Rani Moreles Rubillos’s solution, because it will avoid useless loop.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', listener, true);

function listener() {
  // get elements
  var elts = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  // Reduce array of values
  var val = Object.keys(elts).map(
    function(key) {
      return elts[key]
    }).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return curr.checked ? prev + parseInt(curr.value) : prev
  }, 0);
  document.getElementById('tot').textContent = val
}
```

```html
Aroma Massage:
<input type="checkbox" name="Aroma massage" id="check1" value="55">Swedish Massage:
<input type="checkbox" name="Swedish massage" id="check2" value="50">Hot Stone Massage:
<input type="checkbox" name="Hot Stone massage" id="check3" value="70">Stress Recovery Massage:
<input type="checkbox" name="Stress recovery massage" id="check4" value="25">Thai Massage:
<input type="checkbox" name="Thai massage" id="check5" value="60">

<div id="tot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
 $val = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['chck1']){
        $val += $_POST['chck1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['chck2']){
        $val += $_POST['chck2'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['chck3']){
        $val += $_POST['chck3'];
    }
    echo $val;
```